# How to exclude all but particular files from diff

Tags: regex, linux, shell, diff

I'm aware of how to exclude files from diff using the `diff -x 'pattern' file1 file2` option.  But I intend to exclude ALL files, that don't match "pattern" (kind of an include option). Using an excluding regex didn't do the trick either:

```
pak@idefix:~$ diff -r -x '^?!.*?\bpattern\b)*$' dir1 dir 2
```

I already checked the diff man-page but couldnt find something usefull, so some ideas would be great.

Comment: Have you actually tried to read the `info diff`, the official `diff` documentation?

Comment: Yes, I did. I suggest you misunderstood the question. Excluding files is not the problem. In fact, it's the opposite: to exclude any file but those who match a distinct pattern. I thought a non-matching regex would help, to perform some kind of a double negation, but I didn't work for me so far.

Comment: Perhaps generate a file with all files to be diffed from `dir1` and loop over that file diffing with `dir2`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find -iname` and `diff -X` as `find dir1 dir2 -iname 'pattern' -exec basename {} \; | diff -r -X - dir1 dir2`.